# alguien me puede explicar getchar() != EOF?

Tags: c

No entiendo muy bien como funciona `getchar` y `putchar`, por ejemplo:

```
main()
{
    double nc;
    for (nc=0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
            ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- **getchar()** es una función que permite leer un carácter desde la entrada estándar.
- **putchar()** es una función que te permite escribir un carácter en la salida estándar.

Si revisas la documentación sobre [getchar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) (acostúmbrate a hacerlo si quieres que tus programas funcionen como pretendes), verás que el tipo de retorno es un `int` en vez de un `char`. El motivo es que esta función debe ser capaz de devolver determinados caracteres especiales como el final de archivo (`EOF` para los amigos). Descartando las secuencias especiales (yo ahora mismo únicamente recuerdo `EOF`), el resto de valores pueden ser convertidos tranquilamente a `char` para tus propios propósitos:

```
int valor = getchar();
if( valor != EOF )
{
  char c = (char)valor;
  printf("%c",c);
}
```

En cuanto a [putchar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/putchar), su mecánica es exactamente la misma solo que en vez de leer, escribe en la salida estándar.

A modo de bonus, fíjate que al principio he hablado de *entrada estándar* y *salida estándar* en vez de *teclado* y *consola*. Por defecto el buffer de entrada se rellenará a partir del teclado y el buffer de salida se redirige a la consola, pero ten presente que no tiene por qué ser necesariamente así. Cuando tu ejecutas una aplicación puedes redirigir la entrada y la salida a, por ejemplo, un fichero, de tal forma que la aplicación no leerá el teclado sino un fichero y no imprimirá nada por pantalla sino que volcará una serie de mensajes en el archivo correspondiente.

Es por motivos como este que a veces la documentación de las funciones puede resultar confusa. La gente se acostumbra a hablar de *teclado* y *pantalla* cuando realmente no tiene por qué ser así.

Un ejemplo en Windows podría ser:

```
miApp < ficheroDeEntrada > ficheroDeSalida
```

Y volviendo a tu pregunta. El código que has puesto hace lo siguiente:

- Lee de la entrada estándar elemento a elemento hasta que llega al final.
- Por cada elemento leído incrementa el valor de `nc`. Nota que `nc` es independiente de `getchar`.
- Imprime el valor de `nc`.

Una versión un poco más legible podría ser:

```
main()
{
  int nc = 0; // Para enteros mejor int
  while( getchar() != EOF )
    nc++;

  printf("%d\n", nc);
}
```

Dicho en cristiano. Este programa te muestra la longitud de lo que se encuentre en la entrada estándar.

Un saludo.